# Blazor TypeClient `AddHttpMessageHandler` emits `InvalidOperationException` (ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.)

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I try to apply [ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly additional security scenarios Typed `HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0#typed-httpclient) with OIDC authentication like below,

```cs
// Blazor WebAssembly 'Program.cs'
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

    builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ApplicationHttpClient>(nameof(ApplicationHttpClient), client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

    builder.Services.AddScoped(serviceProvider =>
    {
        return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient(nameof(ApplicationHttpClient));
    });

    builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount>(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("Google", options.ProviderOptions);
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("email");
    }).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount, CustomAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

I met below exceptions if Build & Run,

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.
System.InvalidOperationException: ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.
   at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) in System.Private.CoreLib.dll:token 0x6000fa7+0x43
   at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor) in System.Private.CoreLib.dll:token 0x6000fa8+0x22
   at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].CreateValue() in System.Private.CoreLib.dll:token 0x6000fad+0x74
   at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].get_Value() in System.Private.CoreLib.dll:token 0x6000fb3+0xa
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateHandler(String name) in Microsoft.Extensions.Http.dll:token 0x6000065+0xe
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateClient(String name) in Microsoft.Extensions.Http.dll:token 0x6000064+0xe
```

If I comment out `AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>()`, it works well like before.

> .NET 6.0.100-preview.5 21302.13
> Visual Studio 2019 16.10.2

#### To Reproduce

[Github](https://github.com/ibocon/StackOverflow/tree/68093493)

1. Run 'TypedHttpClient.Server'
2. Navigate to 'FetchData' menu
3. View console error message.

Exception comes from `DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs`.

```
// Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs
public HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }

    // Here
    ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry entry = _activeHandlers.GetOrAdd(name, _entryFactory).Value;

    StartHandlerEntryTimer(entry);

    return entry.Handler;
}
```

#### 2021.06.24 Update

I test `AddHttpMessageHandler` method with `NoobHandler` like below.

```
public class NoobHandler : DelegatingHandler
{

}
```

Instead `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler`, add `NoobHandler` works.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<NoobHandler>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<WeatherForecastClient>(nameof(WeatherForecastClient),
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
.AddHttpMessageHandler<NoobHandler>();
```

Therefore, I am suspecting `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` constructor didn't create a instance, but `DefaultHttpClientFactory` try to access value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the source of the problem I have been looking for:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33787#issuecomment-1788625106

A circular dependency injection of HttpClient could cause this. Such as this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AppHttpMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyApi", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiBaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<AppHttpMessageHandler>();
```

If you try to inject `HttpClient` to `AuthenticationService` or `AppHttpMessageHandler`, you will get this error:
`ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance`

Try using the `IHttpClientFactory` independent service to solve this issue.